# Exit status of process started with open()

Tags: ruby

What is the exist status of a process opened with open() e.g.:

```
f = open("|#{cmd}", 'r')
while char = f.getc
  do something ...
end
f.????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` will contain the exit status after you have closed `f`. e.g.

```
irb(main):024:0> f = open("|#{cmd}", "r")
=> #<IO:0x2d7e9dc>
# read from f here
irb(main):025:0> f.close
=> nil
irb(main):026:0> $?
=> #<Process::Status: pid=3576,exited(0)>
irb(main):027:0> $?.exitstatus
=> 0
```

Comment: ahh damn i had something like this, but it did not work because i did not .close :D
Tanks!!